# Emgu OpenCV: Apply different Threshold values depending on text form[sharp/bold]

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, ocr, emgucv

I want to preprocess a scanned image to do some OCR on it. My problem is that when I apply a given value of Threshold to  remove noise, the bold text become sharp,but the rest of the text disappears.

```
CvInvoke.cvThreshold(img, img, 80, 255, THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

[image]

```
CvInvoke.cvThreshold(img, img, 120, 255, THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

[image]

I'm asking if there is a way to apply different values of Threshold depending on text form ?

Comment: A better approach would be to equalize both images using certain criteria and then apply an automated thresholding algorithm like Otsu or clustering.

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested. I think you'd rather equalize your image in order to extract the borders only.

I would first invert the colours, then use EqualizeHist which will allow you to make your text darker and brighten the background.

Afterwards, you would like to extract the edges. I'd apply Canny while keeping a ratio of 2:1 or 3:1 between the two thresholds, then increase/decrease them accordingly until I'll have a good looking edge.